# How to use the YouTube API V3 to query only 360 videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have been unsuccessful in finding a way of using the YouTube API to query videos based on features. I would like to be able to search only videos that are 360 degrees. YouTube in a browser offers filters for searches as seen below.

[image: Screenshot of YouTube filters dropdown]

Is there any method that allows searching based on these features or based on specific video metadata, like whether a video is sperical or not?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to look for supporting documents regarding 360 degree videos too and I only found about property `contentDetails.projection` in [Videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#properties) with the following valid values:

- 360
- rectangular

Currently, there still has no mention for ways on searching 360 degree videos in [VideoCategories: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list) or in [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list).

Looking further, it was mentioned in [Watch 360 degree videos in Cardboard](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6239930?hl=en) to use `#360Video` in searching for these kind of videos if you wish to watch in YouTube. However, it's not included in any documents if we can use it in getting the list of videos.

I hope that helps. :)

Comment: Thanks, Teyam. Unfortunately, this doesn't get me any further. Seems very strange to make it so hard to search for 360 videos through the api.